# Rails validation if a conditon is met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have this validation

```
 validates :contact_id, :presence => true, :uniqueness => {:message => 'has an account already.'}
```

in the application.rb model

All is good but I need to only do this validation if the state is "invalid"

For example in the applications table there is a field called `state` and if there is a application with a `contact_id` of a user and the state is "invalid" then this validation should not take effect and should let the user save the application

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this should do it:

```
validates :contact_id,
    :presence => true,
    :uniqueness => {:message => 'has an account already.'},
    :if => :invalid?

def invalid?
    state == 'invalid'
end
```

you could also inline that to:

```
validates :contact_id,
    :presence => true,
    :uniqueness => {:message => 'has an account already.'},
    :if => lambda{ state == 'invalid' }
```

Hope this helps.

If you are going to do it when the state is `not` invalid, then you could do that two ways:

```
validates :contact_id,
    :presence => true,
    :uniqueness => {:message => 'has an account already.'},
    :unless => :invalid?
```

Or you could change it a bit more and have a valid message, which I might prefer:

```
validates :contact_id,
    :presence => true,
    :uniqueness => {:message => 'has an account already.'},
    :if => :valid?

def valid?
    state != 'invalid'
end
```

Comment: ok so i am confused if i need the validation to take effect only if the previous application "doesnt" have a state as invalid...so what it be =!

Comment: right, for when it is not invalid, then you would just say state != 'invalid'

Answer (score 4):

Did you try seeing this railscasts video ? http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations

```
validates :contact_id, :if => :should_validate_contactid?

def should_validate_contactid?
   Check condition
end
```